# How to execute a Java Applet in the sandbox?

Tags: java, applet, sandbox

I am using a simple `applet` tag in a web page to embed a java applet. When I launch the page and the applet, there is a security warning saying that the applet will run in unrestricted mode.

But I don't need the unrestricted functions. I just need the basic sandbox security model. How to tell the browser that I want to run in the sandbox mode ?

this is the code of my page:

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <applet code="myPackage.myClass" codebase="." archive="myArchive.jar" width="100%" height="100%">
            </applet>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you modify your java.policy file found in {jdk}/jre/lib/security to grant all permissions to the url from which the applet is fetched from?

Comment: Your report seems very odd.  1) Is the Jar digitally signed?  2) Are you prompted to trust the code when the page is loading?  3) Is the applet publicly availalbe for us to visit?  What URL?  4) What is the (copy/pasted please) output of [these properties](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.vendor.url%2Cjava.version%2Cjava.vm.specification.version%2Cjava.vm.version&format=TSV) in the problem browser?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Yes. It's self-signed. This is why I get this error. Please post your answer as a question so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try giving the applet

```
 <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djava.security.manager">
```

`java_arguments` passes the parameter to the JVM, and `-Djava.security.manager` causes the default applet security manager to be used.